# A simple jQuery function doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Following is the simple jQuery function but I couldn't figure it out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Screen Class</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

   //<![CDATA[
   function getFocus()
   {               
        document.getElementById("txtScreenClassCode").focus();                
   }  

   $(document).ready(function() 
   {                            
        $("#txtScreenClassCode").keypress(function(event) 
        {                                
            if (event.keyCode==46 || event.keyCode==8|| event.keyCode==9 || event.keyCode>=35 && event.keyCode<=40) 
            {
                // let it happen, don't do anything                       
            }
            else 
            {                               
                if (event.charCode<48 || event.charCode>57 || event.charCode==16) 
                {                            
                        event.preventDefault(); 
                }       
            }                  
        });
    });
   //]]>
</script>

</head>
<body onload="getFocus();">

<input type="text" id="txtScreenClassCode"  
    name="txtScreenClassCode"style="background-color: white">

</body>
</html>
```

---

In the above code the jQuery function `$(document).ready(function()` doesn't work. It is meant to allow only digits in the `TextField` mentioned. The browser shows an error at the beginning of this function i.e on this line itself `$(document).ready(function()` that indicates that **Object expected**. What should be wrong with this function? I have teated it with IE and Mozilla Firefox and I also tried to put it into a different directory and enclosed it within the `CDATA` tag but not to avail.

Comment: @Bhavesh - Perhaps [reading the jQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) would help you become less new to jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include jQuery library on the page.

If you don't have jQuery in your application you can include it from one of the jQuery CDN's mentioned here http://www.jquerycdn.net

If you don't know how to include jQuery just add this `script` tag inside the `head` section of your page markup.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This will include jQuery 1.7 minified js file from `Google Ajax API CDN`